# Error passing state in REACT from App.js to Component.js via route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, state

So I've been learning React for a while, but one of the key's in what I have yet succeeded is passing states.

What I'm trying to do is passing a state from my App.js to a component rendered via route. Unfortunately, in MyComponent.js, I get error message 'lang is undefined'.

Can someone guide me to a solution?
This is what I have so far:

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {

constructor (props) {
    super (props)
    this.state = {
        language: 'en'
    }
}   
render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div className='App'>
                <Switch>
                    <Route 
                    exact path='/' render={(props) => <MyComponent lang={this.state.language} />}
                    />
                    <Route exact path='/privacy/policy' component={Policy} />
                    <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
} } export default App;
```

**MyComponent.js**

```
export class MyComponent extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        lang : {lang} 
    }
}
render () {
    return (
        <div className='searchBar'>
            <p>Current language is: {this.state.lang}</p>// HERE COMES THE STATE
        </div>
    );
}}
```

Comment: State is _specific_ to each component and should not be passed to other components. What you really need is passing **_props_**, not state

Comment: Thanks for telling me this, I did not now states couldn't be passed!

Comment: It seems that my explanation was a bit wrong. Actually state data **_might_** be passed, but via **_props_**. This mean that in child component passed data should be accessed via **_props_**, not _state_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass `props` down to `MyComponent` component but you are trying to render it in `SearchBar` component. Rename `SearchBar` to `MyComponent` in the first route of your `App.js`.

Also, in `MyComponent.js`, remove the `lang` property from `state` and change:

```
<p>Current language is: {this.state.lang}</p>
```

to

```
<p>Current language is: {this.props.lang}</p>
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but it renders nothing; just 'Current language is:' I also console.logged 'this.props' but the state is not in it.

Comment: You are passing props to `MyComponent` but you are trying to render it in `SearchBar` component.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you!